# RedisOperationsSessionRepository : Unable to publish SessionDestroyedEvent for session warning

Tags: java, session, redis

2018-07-18 11:52:18.583  WARN 15726 --- [erContainer-158] s.s.d.r.RedisOperationsSessionRepository : Unable to publish SessionDestroyedEvent for session c9587a19-0bdc-407f-b93b-161279ce972f

what happend with spring boot redis session?

Comment: Seems to be because of an expired session.
[source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java#L558)